# Using Seaborn's `factorplot`after using `groupby`

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot, seaborn

I began with a very large Pandas dataframe, of format:

```
DAY     FLAVOR    PRICE    #CREATED    BOUGHT
 1       apple      5         1         1
 1       apple      5         3         7
 1       apple      5         4         2
 1       apple      5         5         3
 2       apple      5         1         1
 2       apple      5         3         9
 2       apple      5         4         8
                 . 
                 .  
                 .
```

after doing a `groupby(['DAY','FLAVOR','PRICE']).mean()`, I wind up with a  reduced dataframe similar to:

```
DAY     FLAVOR    PRICE    BOUGHT
 1       apple      5       3.4
                   25       2.9
         cherry     5       1.7
                   25       2.6
 2       apple      5       1.6
                   25       1.7
         cherry     5       3.1
                   25       3.2
                 . 
                 . 
                 .
```

At this point, I'd like to create Seaborn factorplots of: X = DAY, Y = BOUGHT, and Hue = FLAVOR. Do I need to melt this "reduced" dataframe before plotting? Or is there an easy way to plot the data from my current dataframe?

Comment: Melting, no... reindexing, maybe...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do df.reset_index() and then do a factor plot selecting the appropriate columns.

This means:

```
fg = (
    df.groupby(['DAY', 'FLAVOR', 'PRICE'])
      .mean()
      .reset_index()
      .pipe((sns.factorplot, 'data'), x='DAY', y='BOUGHT', hue='FLAVOR')
)
```

Comment: The `.reset_index()` command followed by a `factorplot` worked perfectly! Just what I was looking for, thank you.